# App can find view on local but not once uploaded to server

Tags: node.js, express, pug

So I have this app:

https://github.com/jfny/SocialGrowth.xyz

If you were to git clone and npm install/npm start on your local, it should work fine.

However when I upload the files to my server and try running, it tells me it is unable to look up one of the views, yet the files haven't changed at all.

Why is this?

Comment: I can't find view files for profile, reset and forgot in your views/pages/account directory. do they exists?

Comment: You're asking us to undertake a vague debugging exercise across your entire application.  Could you please narrow it down and post the relevant code?